# iPad HTML5 Audio Tracks Not Resetting

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios4, ipod, html5-audio

For some odd reason the HTML5 Audio API won't give me access to currentTime in iOS 4 and 5 for iPads and iPods. I need to adjust currentTime whenever an audio element is played, but it acts like the current time isn't accessible. Looked everywhere for an answer on this and I can't figure it out. My code below works fine in all modern browsers, so I'm a bit stumped.

My HTML markup

```
<p>
    <a class="audio" href="assets/audio/ambient-sounds-1.mp3" data-flash="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/niftyplayer.swf" data-mp3="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/ambient-sounds-1.mp3" data-ogg="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/ambient-sounds-1.ogg">
        Ambient Sounds
        <span class="audio-play">Play</span>
        <audio preload="">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/ambient-sounds-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/ambient-sounds-1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </a>
</p>

<p>
    <a class="audio" href="assets/audio/city_street.mp3" data-flash="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/niftyplayer.swf" data-mp3="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/city_street.mp3" data-ogg="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/city_street.ogg">
        City Street Sounds
        <span class="audio-play">Play</span>
        <audio preload="">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/city_street.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/city_street.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </a>
</p>

<p>
    <a class="audio" href="#" data-flash="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/niftyplayer.swf" data-mp3="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/crash.mp3" data-ogg="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/crash.ogg">
        Loud Crash
        <span class="audio-play">Play</span>
        <audio preload="">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/crash.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source preload="" src="http://athens.sierrabravo.net/~ablue/plato/videoplayer/assets/audio/crash.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
    </a>
</p>
```

My JavaScript

```
AudioPlayer = {
    init: function () {
        var player = this;
        this.audio = $('.audio'); // Save and cache all audio elements so they can be targeted by mass stop()

        player.audio.each( function() {
            // Bind each audio element
            player.bind($(this));
        });
    },

    bind: function (object) {
        var player = this;

        object.bind('touchstart click', function() {

            // get the real DOM element, not the jQuery array
            var audio = $(this).find('audio').get(0);

            if(audio.paused) { // Check if its playing
                player.play(audio);
            }
            else {
                player.stop(audio);
            }

            return false;
        });
    },

    play: function(audio) {
        // Stop all existing audio elements and set them to 0
        this.audio.each( function() {
            var audioOther = $(this).find('audio').get(0);
            audioOther.pause();
        });

        // Play the audio element
        if(audio.currentTime) audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
    },

    stop: function(audio) {       
        if(audio.currentTime) audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
    }

};
```

Comment: what error does it send back?

Comment: Actually it isn't firing an error due to if (audio.currentTime). But if I try to forcefully set the currentTime it says "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."

Comment: O and this error fires on all the elements that you didn't click, not the clicked element since it seems to be successfully loaded into memory.

Comment: Looks like the answer to iOS might be just using one audio element and replacing the source when you need to play a new file. Testing right now, will post more info when I'm done experimenting unless someone else comes up with a better solution before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer as to why my code doesn't work, iOS 4 and 5 need the entire audio element to be completely destroyed (terrible solution, but it works). Here is a quick rundown on how to fix my issue if you've run into it.

1. Insert only 1  element into the page (I inserted mine right before the closing  tag).
2. On click to play a new audio element, completely destroy the existing  and rebuild it from scratch with the new track you want to play.
3. Call .play on the audio element and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem and googled then found this page and the below page

http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/

this guy probably found the more detailed answer.

Comment: I spent many hours attempting to get his solution to work. For some reason, iOS 4 refused to cooperate sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I had these types of problems, and I too started using that desperate way to solve the issue which consists of recreating the audio component, reloading the source, etcetera.

A day or two ago I found that the source of the media content must be "pure" to be able to use it successfully from the ipad.

I want to express with "pure" all content that is not being "transmuted" by previous code that could change or delete it's metadata before it reaches the ipad client.

In the current project I am working on, I found that with Ipad I could not replay nor traverse to mm:ss any content located in the "documents" folder, but if I got that file and moved elsewhere, it worked perfectly, I could replay it on my ipad, go to the minute:second I wished, etcetera.

In my case, an .htaccess was forcing my apache server to send the "get" query through a "download.php" which was checking permissions and doing weird stuff of the like, and then this download.php was dispatching the file to the client, but not in a good way or a way more of the ipad's liking.

I removed the .htaccess bindings and the ipad got a nice audio handling again. (That download.php was of not too much good use anyway...)

Comment: Well the issue isn't data transfers, its iPad memory buffering. Thank you for sharing, hadn't heard of this issue before.